# NLP - what are some techniques used to predict the next word in a sentence?

Tags: natural-language

I'm currently going through Speech and Language Processing 2nd.ed by Jurafsky and Martin.

I've just finished the fourth chapter on n-grams which talks about working out ngram probabilties using the Markov Assumption.

I'm assuming that one ngram technique to predict the next word in a sentence is to go through all bigrams which consist of the given word coming first, then count up the bigram frequencies and use the one that occurs the most.

I'm sure the book will probably talk about them later but what are some other statistical or none statistical methods of predicting the next word?

Comment: Check out this presentation *Interpreting, Training and Distilling Seq2Seq Models* by Alexander Rush ... http://nlp.seas.harvard.edu/seq2seq-talk/slidescmu.pdf

Comment: @DJohnson cheers I'll check it out